# Positioning of box and action buttons in R shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

The following dashboard page consists of action buttons aligned to the left and the plot and two more zoom and reset buttons. I want to position the box at the center of the screen and zoom and reset buttons to the extreme top-right. Rest all buttons are fine. I tried to use tags$div but no help. Please help and big thanks in advance.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 0
),
dashboardBody(
                     tags$br(actionButton("go", "Log")),
                     tags$br(),
                     tags$br(actionButton("go", "Case")),
                     tags$br(),
                     tags$br(actionButton("go", "Resource")),
                     tags$br(),
                     tags$br(actionButton("go", "Activity")),
                     tags$br(),
                     tags$br(actionButton("go", "Resource-activity")),
                     box(),
                     tags$br(actionButton("go", "Zoom")),
                     tags$br(actionButton("go", "Reset"))
                     ))

server <- function(input, output)
{ 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could play with `fluidRow` and `column`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 0
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(2, offset = 1,
             actionButton("go", "Log")
      ),
      column(2, offset = 7,
             actionButton("go", "Zoom")
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(2, offset = 1,
             actionButton("go", "Case")
      ),
      column(2, offset = 7,
             actionButton("go", "Reset")
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(2, offset = 1,
             actionButton("go", "Resource")
      ),
      column(8, offset = 1,
             box()
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(2, offset = 1,
             actionButton("go", "Activity")
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(2, offset = 1,
             actionButton("go", "Resource-activity")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But there might be better alternatives.

Comment: Hi I need your help with post, kindly suggest, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920689/displaying-data-in-the-chart-based-on-plotly-click-in-r-shiny/47921511#47921511

Answer (score 2):

Something like this do?

```
  ## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 0
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(1,
             tags$br(actionButton("go", "Log")),
             tags$br(),
             tags$br(actionButton("go1", "Case")),
             tags$br(),
             tags$br(actionButton("go2", "Resource")),
             tags$br(),
             tags$br(actionButton("go3", "Activity")),
             tags$br(),
             tags$br(actionButton("go4", "Resource-activity"))),
      br(),
      column(10,
             box(width=12,plotOutput("plot"))),
      column(1,
             tags$br(actionButton("go5", "Zoom")),
             tags$br(),
             tags$br(actionButton("go6", "Reset"))))
  ))

server <- function(input, output){ 

  output$plot <- renderPlot(hist(mtcars$disp))

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you So much, But this table is not aligned to the center, like I need it to the right of the Log button exactly between the left and right buttons.

Comment: Im speculating here, can you draw a picture with paint or something showing what you need?

Comment: Done, please check and help me.

Comment: Have a look, I added a plot on top of it, you can remove it if you like

Comment: Great Sir, Thank you So much, just one small add on help,the buttons on the right are appearing vertical like one below the other on my screen, please suggest